# How to cleanly handle errors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am new to python and I was wondering what was the best, cleanest, most optimized way to pass data and errors throughout the code.

I thought of something like this:

```
from typing import Final
import sys
import inspect

# Defining constants
FAILURE: Final = False
SUCCESS: Final = True

# Error log
errors = []

# Extracts the data, or log an error with current function name for reference.
def get_data(ret, my_list):
    if (data := my_list.get("item1")) is false:
        ret = FAILURE
        errors.append("Unable to retrieve data in: {}".format(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name))
    return err, data

# Init
ret = SUCCESS
my_list = {"item1": "mouse", "item2": "keyboard"}

# Function call to retrieve data
ret, data = get_data(ret, my_list)

# Test and print result
if ret != SUCCESS:
    print (errors)
else:
    print (data)
```

I am not sure what the conventions are in Python and what is considered a good Python-way of doing it.
Thank you to anyone who took the time to read!

Comment: This first part of your code looks invalid to me

Comment: there is a `logging` module (built-in) and `try/except` blocks, I don't exactly understand what you want to do

Comment: Global variables and functions with side-effects are definitely not "pythonic". If an error is being ignored then log it and if it isn't then raise it

Comment: I see. I guess I overcomplicated it a bit. Thank you!